# How to write messages into a FIFO and read it from another process simultaneously

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cat, fifo

In Unix system, I just knew that we could use FIFO file for communication between two processes and I've tested it with C projects.

Now I'm wondering if we can do something like this:

- Open two terminals.
- Use one to write messages into a FIFO and use the
  other to read it.
- When I put something into the FIFO at the first terminal, the second terminal will show it immediately.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work. On one terminal:

```
mkfifo fifo.file
echo "hello world" > fifo.file
```

On the other terminal:

```
cat fifo.file
```

Now I can see the `"hello world"`. However, both processes finish immediately and I can't continue typing / reading the `fifo.file`anymore.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `info mkfifo`:

> Once you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any process
>   can open it for reading or writing, in the same way as an ordinary file.
>   However, it **has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can
>   proceed to do any input or output operations on it**.  Opening a FIFO for
>   reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for
>   writing, and vice versa.

So you should open the file for reading in one process (terminal):

```
cat fifo.file
```

And open the file for writing in another process (terminal):

```
echo 'hello' > fifo.file
```

`cat` in the sample above stops reading from the file when the end of file(input) occurs. If you want to continue reading from the file, use `tail -F` command, for instance:

```
tail -F fifo.file
```

If you want to write and simultaneously send the strings to another end of the pipe, use `cat` as follows:

```
cat > fifo.file
```

The strings will be sent to another end of the pipe as you type. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to stop writing.

Comment: Thanks. It works now! Could you read my question again because I've a new question.